# Changing Wordpress blog post title

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I would like to change the title of my blog posts. I can't do that in the theme. It needs to be done with a filter.

I have added the following code to the functions.php in the theme that is used on my Wordpress blog:

```
function overwrite_post_title($title, $sep) {
    //global $post;
    //if ( is_single($post->ID) && !is_attachment($post->ID) )
    //if ( is_single() && !is_attachment() )

    var_dump($title);

    $title = "Test";

    return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'overwrite_post_title', 10, 2);
```

It is supposed to change the title of a post.
But it does nothing. It is not even being executed.

Comment: works fine for me. where have you placed this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code or increase your `priority` to large value

```
function overwrite_post_title($title="", $sep="") {
    $title = "Test";
    return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'overwrite_post_title', 10, 2);
```

You increse `priority` by

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'overwrite_post_title', 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
function ta_modified_post_title ($title) {
  if ( in_the_loop() && !is_page() ) {
    $title = "Test (modified title)"; // your title name
  }
  return $title;
}
```